# How to get past SQLException: Attempting to obtain a connection from a pool that has already been shutdown

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick, specs2

I've got a Play (v 2.2.0) app using Typesafe Slick (v 1.0.1), and I'm trying to write a test (specs2) that seeds a PostgreSQL database, then makes a call to various controller actions to validate the existence of the data. In my test, I have:

```
 "Countries" should {
      "initialize" in {
        running(FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase())) {
          AppDB.database.withSession {
            implicit session: Session =>

              AppDB.dal.create
              AppDB.dal.seedForTests

              AppDB.dal.Countries.findAll().size must be_>=(1)
          }
        }
      }
```

by itself, this works fine. But, when I add another test action, like:

```
  "respond to Index()" in {
    val result = controllers.Countries.index()(FakeRequest())

    status(result) must equalTo(OK)
  }
```

my test fails with the message:

```
SQLException: Attempting to obtain a connection from a pool that has already been shutdown.
```

The relevant parts of the stacktrace are:

```
[error]     SQLException: Attempting to obtain a connection from a pool that has already been shutdown. 
[error] Stack trace of location where pool was shutdown follows:
[error]  java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1503)
[error]  com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.captureStackTrace(BoneCP.java:559)
[error]  com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCP.shutdown(BoneCP.java:161)
[error]  com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource.close(BoneCPDataSource.java:143)
[error]  play.api.db.BoneCPApi.shutdownPool(DB.scala:414)
[error]  play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStop$1.apply(DB.scala:264)
[error]  play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin$$anonfun$onStop$1.apply(DB.scala:262)
[error]  scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
[error]  play.api.db.BoneCPPlugin.onStop(DB.scala:262)
...
```

I've tried moving both the `FakeApplication(...)` and `AppDB.database.withSession` blocks higher in the code, as well as wrapping the `val result = controllers.Countries.index(...)` code in an `AppDB.database.withSession` wrapper, but still have had no luck.

Thank you for any direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `AroundExample` to initialise your DB and run your tests:

```
class CountriesSpec extends mutable.Specification with AroundExample {

  def around[R : AsResult](r: =>R) = 
    running(FakeApplication(additionalConfiguration = inMemoryDatabase())) {
      AppDB.database.withSession { implicit session: Session =>
        AppDB.dal.create
        AppDB.dal.seedForTests
        AppDB.dal.Countries.findAll().size must be_>=(1)
        // just AsResult(r) with the latest 2.2.3 specs2 
        AsResult.effectively(r)
      }
    }

  "Countries" should {
    "respond to Index()" in {
      val result = controllers.Countries.index()(FakeRequest())
      status(result) must equalTo(OK)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked, but I found some documentation on the Play site that I ended up going with. See here: https://gist.github.com/jbnunn/7102350